# Which maps are isomorphisms

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Determine whether the map $\phi: G \to G'$ is as isomorphism

a) $G = \mathbb{Z}, G' = \langle a \rangle $(infinite cyclic group with operations expressed as a product) $\phi(j) = a^{-4j}, j \in \mathbb{Z}$
My solution: It is not an isomorphism since it is not order preserving, i.e. if we choose i =2, j =-2, for $i,j \in \mathbb{Z}$

b) $G = G' = D_5$ and let $\phi(a) = a^3, a \in D_5$. Im having a bit of trouble proving the function is a bijection and is order preserving.

c)$G = G' =GL(2,\mathbb{R}), \phi(A) = (A^t)^{-1}$. Im a bit confused about this one, if i choose, $A_{1,1}=A_{1,2}=0$ then wont the matrix not be invertable, and therefore not onto?

Any help would be apprecited,

Thanks

Comment: The map in the first one does preserve order (none of those groups have any elements of finite order apart from the neutral element).

Comment: Does the function of b) preserve the group operation ?

Comment: @Amr your right, im trying out everything but since it is mod 5 my examples are working out, which direction should i be looking at?

Answer (score 1):

a) As $\langle a \rangle$ is infinite, $a \neq 1$. Thus there does not exist an $j \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $\phi(j) = a^{-4j} = a \in \langle a \rangle$, otherwise $|a|=4j+1$; hence $\phi$ is not surjective.

b) Consider $D_{10} = \langle x,a \mid a^5 = x^2 = e, xax^{-1} = a^{-1} \rangle$, where $x$ and $a$ can be regarded as reflection and rotation, respectively. Then $\phi(ax) = (ax)^3 = ax$, but $\phi(a) \phi(x) = a^3 x^3 = a^3 x$, so $\phi$ is not a homomorphism.

c) Let $A,B \in GL(2,\mathbb{R})$. We note that $\phi(AB) = ((AB)^T)^{-1} = (B^T A^T)^{-1} = (A^T)^{-1} (B^T)^{-1}$ and $\phi(A) \phi(B) = (A^T)^{-1} (B^T)^{-1}$, so $\phi$ is a homomorphism. Furthermore, $\phi$ is a composition of two bijective functions, so it is bijective. Hence it is an isomorphism.